# Do we have only 4 revelations by name?

Tags: revelation

I have often heard apologist muslim speakers like zakir Naik say that muslims believe in 4 heavenly books.

My question is do we have only four or are there others?

In surah al-ala it is mentioned scripture of ibrahim in last verse.

Doesnt this count as a revelation?

Answer (score 1):

Allah has revealed His Books to various Prophets for the guidance of their nations.

There are two types of Books:

- Kitaabs (the **big** Books)
- Sahifas (the **small** Books)

The **four main** Kitaabs are:

- Tawrat (Old Testament)
- Zaboor (Psalms)
- Injeel (New Testament)
- Quran

Besides these Books, there were **smaller Books revealed known as Sahifas.**

- 10 Sahifas were revealed to Hazrat Ādam(as)
- 50 Sahifas were revealed to Hazrat Shees(as)
- 30 Sahifas were revealed to Hazrat Idrees(as)
- 10-30 Sahifas were revealed to Hazrat Ibrahim(as)

Verses where the Scriptures of Ibrahim and Musa are mentioned:

> > So remind, if the reminder should benefit;
> >     He who fears [ Allah ] will be reminded.
> >     But the wretched one will avoid it -
> >     [He] who will [enter and] burn in the greatest Fire,
> >     Neither dying therein nor living.
> >     He has certainly succeeded who purifies himself
> >     And mentions the name of his Lord and prays.
> >     But you prefer the worldly life,
> >     While the Hereafter is better and more enduring.
> >     Indeed, this is in the former scriptures,
> >     **The scriptures of Abraham and Moses.**
> >
> > ([Quran 87:9-19](https://quran.com/87/9-19))

---

> > Or has he not been informed of what was in the scriptures of Moses
> >     And [of] Abraham, who fulfilled [his obligations]
> >
> > ([Quran 53:36-37](https://quran.com/53/36-37))

The Scriptures of Ibrahim are Sahifas.

And Allah knows best.

Comment: Source please for 10,50 sahifas. Suhufu ibrahima wa musa it says musa also give suhuf. Quran is also called musaf.

Comment: A book called Taleemul Haq

Comment: @Preordainment **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for seeking clarification and constructive criticism, not for arguing about which madhhab is "more correct". Please see also the meta discussion at "[Why Sectarianism is Ruining Your Site](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22)".