# what are the 4 holy books mentioned in the Quran?

Tags: quran, reference-request, revelation

I have heard talk of 4 books mentioned in the quran. Ca anyone explain what these books are and who they are directed at?

Answer (score 1):

The Quran mentions 3 previous revelations.

Tawrat (Torah) sent to Mussa (moses)
Zabur (the psalms) sent to Dawud (king David)
Injil (the bible) Sent to Isa (Jesus)
The Tawrat in quran

> إِنَّا أَنزَلْنَا التَّوْرَاةَ فِيهَا هُدًى وَنُورٌ ۚ يَحْكُمُ بِهَا
>   النَّبِيُّونَ الَّذِينَ أَسْلَمُوا لِلَّذِينَ هَادُوا
>   وَالرَّبَّانِيُّونَ وَالْأَحْبَارُ بِمَا اسْتُحْفِظُوا مِن كِتَابِ
>   اللَّهِ وَكَانُوا عَلَيْهِ شُهَدَاءَ ۚ فَلَا تَخْشَوُا النَّاسَ
>   وَاخْشَوْنِ وَلَا تَشْتَرُوا بِآيَاتِي ثَمَنًا قَلِيلًا ۚ وَمَن لَّمْ
>   يَحْكُم بِمَا أَنزَلَ اللَّهُ فَأُولَٰئِكَ هُمُ الْكَافِرُونَ - 5:44
>
> Indeed, We sent down the Torah, in which was guidance and light. The
>   prophets who submitted [to Allah ] judged by it for the Jews, as did
>   the rabbis and scholars by that with which they were entrusted of the
>   Scripture of Allah, and they were witnesses thereto. So do not fear
>   the people but fear Me, and do not exchange My verses for a small
>   price. And whoever does not judge by what Allah has revealed - then it
>   is those who are the disbelievers.
>
> T

he zabur in quran

> وَرَبُّكَ أَعْلَمُ بِمَن فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ ۗ وَلَقَدْ
>   فَضَّلْنَا بَعْضَ النَّبِيِّينَ عَلَىٰ بَعْضٍ ۖ وَآتَيْنَا دَاوُودَ
>   زَبُورًا - 17:55
>
> "And your Lord is most knowing of whoever is in the heavens and the
>   earth. And We have made some of the prophets exceed others [in various
>   ways], and to David We gave the book [of Psalms]."

The Injil in the quran

> ثُمَّ قَفَّيْنَا عَلَىٰ آثَارِهِم بِرُسُلِنَا وَقَفَّيْنَا بِعِيسَى
>   ابْنِ مَرْيَمَ وَآتَيْنَاهُ الْإِنجِيلَ وَجَعَلْنَا فِي قُلُوبِ
>   الَّذِينَ اتَّبَعُوهُ رَأْفَةً وَرَحْمَةً وَرَهْبَانِيَّةً
>   ابْتَدَعُوهَا مَا كَتَبْنَاهَا عَلَيْهِمْ إِلَّا ابْتِغَاءَ رِضْوَانِ
>   اللَّهِ فَمَا رَعَوْهَا حَقَّ رِعَايَتِهَا ۖ فَآتَيْنَا الَّذِينَ
>   آمَنُوا مِنْهُمْ أَجْرَهُمْ ۖ وَكَثِيرٌ مِّنْهُمْ فَاسِقُونَ - 57:27
>
> Then We sent following their footsteps Our messengers and followed
>   [them] with Jesus, the son of Mary, and gave him the Gospel. And We
>   placed in the hearts of those who followed him compassion and mercy
>   and monasticism, which they innovated; We did not prescribe it for
>   them except [that they did so] seeking the approval of Allah . But
>   they did not observe it with due observance. So We gave the ones who
>   believed among them their reward, but many of them are defiantly
>   disobedient.

Comment: Wrong the qur'an mentions at least five and the question is a duplicate. See for example https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40032/13438, https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1141/13438 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29770/13438

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide an answer mentioning the 5th book, or the link for the question that this one is duplicating?